# Python generate fractal tree using class

Tags: python, svg

I would like to generate a fractal tree using the SVG path object. One branch of the tree should be represented by one `Branch` object. I have some problem with my recursion logic and collecting `path`. For `depth=1` the code should generate 4 `path`s but my current code is returning only one such `path`. How can I correct this?

My code:

```
import math


class Branch:

    def __init__(self, pointxy1, pointxy2):
        self.pointXY1 = pointxy1
        self.pointXY2 = pointxy2

    def __str__(self):
        return (r'<path d="M {} {} L {} {}"'' '
                'stroke="rgb(100,60,0)" stroke-width="35"/>')\
            .format(self.pointXY1[0], self.pointXY1[1], self.pointXY2[0], self.pointXY2[1])

    def drawtree(self, lenght, angle, depth):

        if depth:
            self.pointXY2[0] = self.pointXY1[0] + lenght * (math.cos(math.radians(angle)))
            self.pointXY2[1] = self.pointXY1[1] + lenght * (math.cos(math.radians(angle)))

            self.drawtree(lenght, angle - 20, depth - 1)
            self.drawtree(lenght, angle, depth - 1)
            self.drawtree(lenght, angle + 20, depth - 1)

        return Branch(self.pointXY1, self.pointXY2)

tree = [Branch([400, 800], [400, 600]).drawtree(200, -90, 1)]

for t in tree:
    print t
```

And following is the output. It's only 1 path instead of the desired 4.

```
<path d="M 400 800 L 400 600" stroke="rgb(100,60,0)" stroke-width="35"/>
```

EDIT:

This is my non object example it's working:

```
import math


def drawTree(lenght, angle, depth):

    if depth >= 0:

        x1 = 400
        y1 = 800

        x2 = x1 + lenght * (math.cos(math.radians(angle)))
        y2 = y1 + lenght * (math.sin(math.radians(angle)))

        print (r'<path d="M {} {} L {} {}"'' stroke="rgb(100,60,0)" stroke-width="35"/>').format(x1, y1, x2, y2)

        drawTree(lenght, angle - 20, depth - 1)
        drawTree(lenght, angle, depth - 1)
        drawTree(lenght, angle + 20, depth - 1)


drawTree(200, -90, 1)
```

output:

```
<path d="M 400 800 L 400.0 600.0" stroke="rgb(100,60,0)" stroke-width="35"/>
<path d="M 400 800 L 331.595971335 612.061475843" stroke="rgb(100,60,0)" stroke-width="35"/>
<path d="M 400 800 L 400.0 600.0" stroke="rgb(100,60,0)" stroke-width="35"/>
<path d="M 400 800 L 468.404028665 612.061475843" stroke="rgb(100,60,0)" stroke-width="35"/>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Are you meant to return the results of `self.drawtree`?

Comment: Yes, all of recursion result.

Comment: But you don't return the results.

Comment: `return Branch(self.pointXY1, self.pointXY2)` this is not it?

Comment: That's why you only get one branch.

Comment: But, I call `drawtree` function three times, how to correct this? Add to list?

Comment: The only effect of the three calls to `drawtree` is to return three `Branch` objects which you don't do anything with. I don't know what your requirements or data structures are. Maybe returning a list would be right. Do you want nested lists of lists? Your final print statement will have to be recursive too.

Comment: @PeterWood I put example in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a flat list and then iterate it to print it:

```
def drawtree(self, lenght, angle, depth):
    result = []
    if depth:
        self.pointXY2[0] = self.pointXY1[0] + lenght * (math.cos(math.radians(angle)))
        self.pointXY2[1] = self.pointXY1[1] + lenght * (math.cos(math.radians(angle)))

        result.extend(self.drawtree(lenght, angle - 20, depth - 1))
        result.extend(self.drawtree(lenght, angle, depth - 1))
        result.extend(self.drawtree(lenght, angle + 20, depth - 1))

    result.append(Branch(self.pointXY1, self.pointXY2))
    return result
```

Comment: Ok, thanks it works, but only one problem. Values are still the same `<path d="M 400 800 L 400.0 800.0 z" stroke="rgb(100,60,0)" stroke-width="35"/>
<path d="M 400 800 L 400.0 800.0 z" stroke="rgb(100,60,0)" stroke-width="35"/>
<path d="M 400 800 L 400.0 800.0 z" stroke="rgb(100,60,0)" stroke-width="35"/>
<path d="M 400 800 L 400.0 800.0 z" stroke="rgb(100,60,0)" stroke-width="35"/>`

Comment: That's really another question for another time. In your new code don't update `pointXY2` before creating `Branch` but you do in the old code before printing.

Comment: @lukassz Just because you have my ear, doesn't mean I'm going to debug your code for you. Write a good question and post it. First see how to create a [mcve]. In creating it you might work out your problem yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You're making these calls to drawTree but you aren't doing anything with the return value:

```
drawTree(lenght, angle - 20, depth - 1)
drawTree(lenght, angle, depth - 1)
drawTree(lenght, angle + 20, depth - 1)
```

So the returned Branch is just lost. It isn't added to your tree.

The reason your 'non object example' appears to work is that you are doing the print inside the drawTree function, so you get something printed for every Branch. You really have the same problem there though and are also dropping the return value, it's just that you print something first.